# Malloc with structs in C

Tags: c, malloc

I have a struct:

```
struct numbers_struct {
char numbers_array[1000];
};

struct numbers_struct numbers[some_size];
```

After creating struct, there is an integer number as an input:

```
scanf("%d",&size);
```

I need to use `malloc(size)` and specify the size of the array numbers. (instead of some_size use size)

Is something like this possible in C?

Comment: VLA is not there in C, rather use calloc

Comment: @perilbrain: What does everybody have with `calloc`? The only practical difference from `malloc` is that it initializes the memory.

Comment: @JanHudec:- and what about array???

Comment: @perilbrain: No, C does not have variable length arrays. But the question already mentions `malloc`.

Comment: @JanHudec, VLAs were introducted in C99.

Comment: @hmjd: Actually I wanted to mention that under some limited conditions they are, but thought it would be overcomplicating the matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you can do like this

```
 struct numbers_struct {
char numbers_array[1000];
};

scanf("%d",&size);

struct numbers_struct *numbers = malloc(sizeof(numbers_struct) * size);
```

Comment: If this is Pure C, you need to write sizeof(struct numbers_struct). Struct names are automatically typedef in C++ only. Or you have to create a typedef in c while defining the structure

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is but `malloc()` require the total amount of memory require for the array, not the number of elements:

```
struct numbers_struct* numbers = malloc(size * sizeof(*numbers));
if (numbers)
{
}
```

Note that you *must* check the return value of `scanf()` before using `size` (which is a poor name in this case) otherwise the code could be using an uninitialized variable if `scanf()` fails:

```
int number_of_elements;
if (1 == scanf("%d", &number_of_elements))
{
    struct numbers_struct* numbers =
        malloc(number_of_elements * sizeof(*numbers));
    if (numbers)
    {
        free(numbers); /* Remember to release allocated memory
                          when no longer required. */
    }
}
```

Variable length arrays were introduced in C99 but there are restrictions around their use (they cannot be used at file scope for example).

Answer (score 1):

See "calloc" and "alloc" and "realloc" usages in the docs.

Comment: What does everybody have with `calloc`? The only practical difference from `malloc` is that it initializes the memory.

Comment: @JanHudec: #1: Initialization is useful sometimes. #2: Readability - it makes it clear that you allocate N elements of size S. #3: `malloc(n*m)` behaves weird if `n*m` overflows, while `calloc(n,m)` would fail nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int  main(void){
    struct numbers_struct {
        char numbers_array[1000];
    };

    int size = 10;
    int i;
    struct numbers_struct *s= malloc(size * sizeof(struct numbers_struct));

    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        snprintf(s[i].numbers_array, 20, "test index %d", i);
    }

    for (i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%s\n", s[i].numbers_array);
    }

    free(s);
}
```

Comment: No need to cast the result of `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

VLA is possible in C99.

you can do it

```
int main()
{
char *p;//I have used char you can use any pointer
int k;
scanf("%d",&k);
p=malloc(k);//just allocated the memory and given the  memory address to p

//after use 
free(p);
}
```

It will compile without any error.